# Intellij package org.testng does not exist

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

When using Intellij and trying to import TestNG the error is:

java: package org.testng does not exist

What I was doing was trying to import it via pom.xml as a dependency, which does not seem to work at all.

Not sure if other people have had the same issue, also seems there's way  more ppl using eclipse vs intellij when it comes to selenium-java (when looking up questions at least).

Comment: After you change the pom.xml file, run re-import from Maven in Maven projects tool window: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_dependency or configure **Auto-import**.

Answer (score 8):

After much pain and suffering I found this, where Erek Speed will remain a hero of mine for all time:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mariocompetition/dUIPTghCZwc/PEYqu9BqBUYJ

So the steps are:

1. File > Project Structure
2. then click on Libraries on the left side-nav
3. then the "+" button to add, then choose "from Maven"
4. then type in org.testng and click the magnifying glass
5. choose the version you want to use, then click "ok" and "Apply"

The steps are based on using IntelliJ IDEA Community version 2017.2.3

Answer (score 0):

It was same case for me. This may help you.

Do following steps:

1. Place your cusror on class name
2. Alt + Enter
3. Create Test
4. In the Test Library input field. Please select TestNG. Press ok
5. Go to code where you are getting unresolved. e.g. ("Assert".assertEquals)
6. Press Alt + Enter
7. Choose add dependency

All set. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij IDEA , I've faced similar issue.

After adding following dependency , could not found the testNg in IntellijIdea

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The error i've faced: **Dependency 'org.testng:testng:7.8.0' not found**

First solution :

mvn clean
mvn clean install -U

If it does not help , it might be related your local repo , please run following commands on your project:

**mvn dependency:purge-local-repository**
**mvn clean install**